# How to automate karma unit tests with continuous integration

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, continuous-integration, karma-runner, circleci

Currently we run our karma/jasmine unit tests a gulp task: `gulp test`

We are trying to figure out how to get [circleci](https://circleci.com/docs) to run our tests automatically. I tried adding `gulp test` under the `test:` section of the circle.yml file but I get `gulp: command not found`. But I get the same error if I try something basic like `pwd`. So clearly I'm doing something wrong.

I think the same results could be achieved by using the `scripts` property in the package.json, because circleci runs that automatically, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here's our circle.yml file...

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - echo PHP rules

test:
  override:
    - gulp test #this doesnt work!

deployment:
  development:
    branch: dev
    heroku:
      appname: ourapp
```

Here's package.json...

```
{
  "name": "ourapp",
  "private": true,
  "description": "An app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-opera-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "gulp": "~3.8.10",
    "gulp-karma": "0.0.4",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "The A Team"
}
```

Just in case it's useful, here's the gulp task...

```
gulp.task('test', function(){
  return gulp.src(testFiles)
    .pipe(karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: 'run' //change to watch if you want to auto-run 
    }))
    .on('error', function(err){
      throw err;
    })
});
```

For consistency, I think the best would be if we could get circleci to run the gulp task, but it's okay if we have to run `karma ...` manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - npm install -g gulp

test:
  override:
    - gulp test

machine:
  php:
    version: 5.6.2
```

The `npm install -g gulp` was the missing piece for me. Circleci will detect package.json and run `npm install` automatically, but I needed the `pre:` to install it *globally* in order for my gulp task to work.

It's also worth mentioning that circleci automatically knows whether the karma/jasmine tests passed or failed by detecting the exit code. So this just works as-is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the CircleCI devs. What you'll need to do is to specify a NodeJS version to build with in your circle.yml in order to trigger the NodeJS inference rules - https://circleci.com/docs/language-nodejs

Once you've done that we'll run `npm install`, `npm test` etc. automatically.
For `npm test` to do the right thing you'll need to configure your test script correctly. Best to get that running on your local environment first.

You'll probably also need to add `gulp-cli` as a dev dependency too, most NodeJS tools these days split the library and cli binary into separate packages.

Comment: Hi Gordon. You helped me solve this via a support ticket yesterday. Thanks for you help! +1 I posted my finished code below as a reference for others.

Comment: Installing `gulp-cli` as a dev dependency didn't work for me, i needed to run `npm install -g gulp` as @SDP suggested